# Getting an error of : "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'provider')"

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, hardhat, waffle

I am getting this error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'provider')

Here is my code for buy-coffee.js inside of scripts.

```
// We require the Hardhat Runtime Environment explicitly here. This is optional
// but useful for running the script in a standalone fashion through `node <script>`.
//
// You can also run a script with `npx hardhat run <script>`. If you do that, Hardhat
// will compile your contracts, add the Hardhat Runtime Environment's members to the
// global scope, and execute the script.
const {ethers,waffle} = require("hardhat");

async function getBalance(address) {
  const provider = waffle.provider;
  const balanceBigInt = await provider.getBalance(address);
  return ethers.utils.formatEther(balanceBigInt);
}

async function printBalance(addresses) {
  let index = 0;
  for (const address of addresses) {
    console.log(`Address ${index} balance: `, await getBalance(address));
    index++;
  }
}

async function printMemos(memos) {
  for (const memo of memos) {
    const timeStamp = memo.timeStamp;
    const name = memo.name;
    const address = memo.from;
    const message = memo.message;
    console.log(`At ${timeStamp}, ${name}, ${address}, said: "${message}" `);
  }
}

async function main() {
  // Get Example Accounts.
  const [owner, tipper, tipper2, tipper3] = await ethers.getSigners();

  // Get the Contract and deploy.
  const BuyMeACoffee = await ethers.getContractFactory("BuyMeACoffee");
  const buyMeACoffee = await BuyMeACoffee.deploy();
  await buyMeACoffee.deployed();
  console.log(
    `BuyMeACoffee Contract Deployed at Address: ${buyMeACoffee.address}`
  )

  // Check Balances before Coffee Purchase.
  const addresses = [owner.address, tipper.address, buyMeACoffee.address];
  console.log("Addresses: ");
  await printBalance(addresses);
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing `await` keyword.

```
const provider = await waffle.provider;
```

Other than this, you may use ethers for this.
You can get signer as:

```
const signer = await ethers.provider.getSigner(0);
```

Zero gets the 0th index. `getSigners()` gives you an array.

Then,

```
const address = await signer.getAddress();
```

Comment: I tried using await but still it's not working.

Comment: Do the ethers one. It works.

Comment: I got the error my hardhat.config.js file was missing the statement require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle"); Now its working! Thanks though.